# ¿Ayudo cometi un error al subir una aplicacion rails en heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Estaba intentando subir una aplicación a *Heroku*, de hecho ya lo logre pero ejecuté unos comandos y no se si mi información está en riesgo, agradecería la ayuda de esta comunidad; como un detalle extra seguía [este tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73TwV.jpg).

```
C:\Users\Daniel>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials:
Email: mncmdncm@gmail.com
Password: *******
Logged in as mncmdncm@gmail.com
git clone https://github.com/heroku/jruby-getting-started.git
> cd jruby-getting-started
```

Aquí esta lo que ejecute

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué crees que tu información podría estar en riesgo? De acuerdo a la información que muestras, lo único que hiciste fue realizar una copia del repositorio `https://github.com/heroku/jruby-getting-started.git` a tu máquina local, en la ubicación `C:\Users\Daniel\jruby-getting-started`.

Comment: @Gerry Gracias desconocía que era lo que hice ha

Comment: La única información en riesgo que pones es tu email, al postearlo en tu imagen acá. No pongas una imagen del problema, sino colócalo como texto

Answer (score 0):

Tu información **NO** esta en riesgo.

Lo único que hiciste fue clonar el repositorio desde Heroku a tu computador.

Te invito a usar otro sistema operativo para puedas trabajar de mejor manera con **Ruby on Rails**.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/58293)

Comment: @Muriano - ¿Por que no es una respuesta a la pregunta?

Comment: Por la forma y contenido, lo considero más un comentario. @aldanux, además, incluye valoraciones que considero basadas en opiniones.

Comment: @Muriano - La respuesta es totalmente válida ya que el OP pregunta si ha cometido un error... fuera si la pregunta es buena o mala...

Comment: @Muriano La pregunta es clara, la persona quiere saber si puso en riesgo su información.